# How should I handle a potentially infected site linked from a user's About Me in profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I just encountered a user who has a link in his/her bio-website-field that points to a site which google claims to be potentially harmful.

https://www.google.com/?q=jkkn.org

Should I just ignore this?

Comment: Every day sites get hacked or have their advertising usurped for drive-by malware. The site in question is for an educational institution, they are probably not even aware that Google has flagged the domain. Ignore and move on.

Comment: Yeah, what @MartijnPieters says. If something looks purposeful, maybe flag some post (theirs/yours) with "Other" and explain, but usually, just let it be.

Comment: My advice would simply be: don't click it.

Comment: It might be nice to send them an email if there's any contact info in their about me-  they may not know about it.